# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve Object reference not set to an instance of an object in WSDL Soap Service

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API I have give this Soap  Service, http://thirdparty:2022/HrmService/HrmService?WSDL to consume .

I used WCF connected service to generate it, I call it `HrmServiceReference`. Then I write this code:

DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; } = null;
}
```

EmployeeService - interface:

```
Task<EmployeeResponse> GetEmployeeDetailAsync(EmployeeDto model);
```

Implementation:

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly HrmServiceServiceClient _client;

    public EmployeeDetailService(HrmServiceServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<EmployeeResponse> GetEmployeeDetailAsync(EmployeeDto model)
    {
        var request = new QUERYEMPLOYEE_REQ();
        request.HRM_HEADER = new HRM_HEADERType();
        request.HRM_HEADER.USERNAME = "HRMUSN";
        request.HRM_HEADER.PASSWORD = "HRMPSW";

        request.HRM_BODY = new QUERYEMPLOYEE_HRM_BODY();
        request.HRM_BODY.OPR.EMP = model.EmployeeCode;
        request.HRM_BODY.OPR.DEP = model.DepartmentCode;

        var response = await _client.QueryEmployeeAsync(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmployeeDetailService _employeeDetailService;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeDetailService)
    {
        _employeeDetailService = employeeDetailService;
    }

    [HttpGet("EmpDetail")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyEmployeeDetailAsync([FromQuery] EmployeeDto model)
    {
        var result = await _employeeDetailService.GetEmployeeDetailAsync(model);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

In Swagger, I entered the input parameter (`EmployeeCode` and `DepartmentCode`) and submitted.

But I got this error:

> System.NullReferenceException
> HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Both `request.HRM_BODY.OPR.EMP = model.EmployeeCode` and `request.HRM_BODY.OPR.DEP = model.DepartmentCode` are highlighted.

What could be the problem and how do I resolve it?

Comment: You need to instantiate a class on `request.HRM_BODY.OPR` as well.

Comment: @rene - How do I do that?

Comment: You already did that three times, for the request, the header, and the body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)